# filepond file uploader reloads web app when file is still uploading and refreshes current page

Tags: file-upload, multipartform-data, form-submit, page-refresh, filepond

I am using reactjs to create the web app, on a file uploading component, I utilize filepond, it works well, except when I am trying to upload a file, before it's progress reaches beyond 30 or 40 percent, the entire page reloads and the whole file upload process cancels. Is there any way I can stop the page from reloading? my basic filepond component is like this:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import "./ImageUploader.css";
    import { FilePond, registerPlugin } from 'react-filepond/dist/react-filepond';

    // Import FilePond styles
    import 'filepond/dist/filepond.min.css';

    // Import the Image EXIF Orientation and Image Preview plugins
    // Note: These need to be installed separately
    import FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation from 'filepond-plugin-image-exif-orientation';
    import FilePondPluginImagePreview from 'filepond-plugin-image-preview';
    import FilePondPluginFilePoster from "filepond-plugin-file-poster";
    import FilePondPluginFileEncode from 'filepond-plugin-file-encode';
    import 'filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.css';

    // // Register the plugins
    registerPlugin(FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation, FilePondPluginImagePreview,FilePondPluginFilePoster,FilePondPluginFileEncode);

    // Our app
    const api_url = require("../../../../constants/api");

    export default class ImageUploader extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                // Set initial files, type 'local' means this is a file
                // that has already been uploaded to the server (see docs)
                files: [
                    {
                        // the server file reference
                        source: '12345',

                        // set type to local to indicate an already uploaded file
                        options: {
                            type: 'local',
                            // pass poster property
                            metadata: {
                                poster: '../images/file.png'
                            }
                        }
                    }]
            };
        }

        handleInit() {
            console.log('FilePond instance has initialised', this.pond);
        }
        onProcessFiles() {
            let { onProcessFiles } = this.props;
            let pondFiles = this.pond.getFiles();
            if (onProcessFiles) onProcessFiles(pondFiles);
        }



        render() {
            return (
                    <FilePond ref={ref => this.pond = ref}
                            onaddfilestart={(file) => this.onProcessFiles()}
                            onprocessfile={(error, file) => this.onProcessFiles()}
                            allowFilePoster = {true}
                            allowFileEncode = {true}
                            files={this.state.files}
                            allowMultiple={true}
                            maxFiles={3}
                            server={api_url+'/uploads'}
                            onprocessfileabort = {()=>{ console.log("error!!!!")}}
                            oninit={() => this.handleInit() }
                            onupdatefiles={(fileItems) => {
                                // Set current file objects to this.state
                                this.setState({
                                    files: fileItems.map(fileItem => fileItem.file)
                                });
                            }}>
                    </FilePond>

            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see you're using the file-encode plugin, I suspect you're uploading large files which will not work and cause browser issues.

Comment: @Rik I see, but how do I set my max file size limit?

Comment: And how is it that whenever I upload a file of certain size, at times it does upload nicely without the reload, sometimes it doesn't. But the same size. Or lesser a times

Comment: It's probably dependent on how much memory your browser is currently using. I'd advise to not use the file encode plugin, only use it for very small files. You can set a max file size with the file size validate plugin. https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/plugins/file-validate-size/

Comment: Have any body resolve the issue I am as well facing the issue  in vuejs Laravel ,the page gets refresh on process